# Array char operation C#

Tags: c#, arrays

**Anyone can help me how to optimize the code that i create or have better way to implement it?**
The rule is on the bottom

```
    public string HandleLastNumber(char[] n_array)
    {
    var n_string = new StringBuilder();
    if (n_array.All(x => char.IsDigit(x)))
    {
    return $"{new string(n_array)} -> {int.Parse(n_array) + 1}";
    }
    if (!n_array.Any(x => char.IsDigit(x)))
    {
    return $"{new string(n_array)}->{new string(n_array)}";
    }
    for (int i = n_array.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
    if (!char.IsDigit(n_array[i]))
    {
    break;
    }
    n_string.Insert(0, n_array[i]);
    }
    var n_plus = int.Parse(n_string.ToString()) + 1;
    var n_handled = n_plus.ToString()[^n_string.Length..];
    var sub_clone = new string(n_array).Substring(0,n_array.Length-n_handled.Length);
    return $"{new string(n_array)}->{sub_clone += n_handled}";
    }
    }
```

The rule is
Input char array, validate the last number, plus one at last number. then print old and new char array
result example:

1. 00-> 01
2. 99-> 00
3. ABC123 -> ABC124
4. ABCDGF -> ABCDGF
5. AD33GVB99 -> AD33GVB00

Comment: If the input was "AD33GV", what would be the expected output?  Would it be "AD33GV" or "AD34GV"?

Comment: No, it will be "AD33GV", it's only plus 1 at last number, if the last one or multiple are number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to implement this.  I have seen many such posts in the past.  I do not like that your method accepts a `char[]`.  I perfer that the input and output be a `string`.

Implementing the logic becomes more straight forward:

```
public static string IncrementLastDigits(string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    {
        return value; // consider returning null or ""
    }
    var array = value.ToCharArray();
    for (var i = array.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var character = array[i];
        if (!char.IsDigit(character))
        {
            break;
        }
        if (character < '9')
        {
            array[i] = ++character;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            array[i] = '0';
        }
    }
    return new string(array);
}
```

And here's a quick method to test it:

```
public static void TestLastDigits()
{
    var input  = new List<string>() { "00", "99", "ABC123", "ABCDGF", "AD33GVB99", "AD33GV" };
    var answer = new List<string>() { "01", "00", "ABC124", "ABCDGF", "AD33GVB00", "AD33GV" };

    for (var i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
    {
        var output = IncrementLastDigits(input[i]);
        var status = (answer[i] != output) ? $"Correct answer is {answer[i]}" : "";
        Console.WriteLine($"Input {input[i]}, Output {output}  {status}");
    }
}
```